# AutoMapper cannot create an instance of IMemberValueResolver via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I'm getting an error that `AutoMapper v11.0.1` cannot create an instance of a custom `IMemberValueResolver` type.

This is my custom resolver:

```
public class FooCollectionResolver<TModel, TViewModel> : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, BlockListModel?, IEnumerable<TViewModel>?>
 where TModel : class, IPublishedElement
 where TViewModel : class
{
    public IEnumerable<TViewModel>? Resolve(object source, object destination, BlockListModel? sourceMember, IEnumerable<TViewModel>? destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    { }
}
```

It takes a source `BlockListModel` member and returns a collection of `TViewModel`.

Example usage:

```
this.CreateMap<FooModel, FooViewModel>().ForMember(
dest => dest.BlockListModelMember,
src => src.MapFrom<FooCollectionResolver<FooCollectionModel, FooCollectionViewModel>, BlockListModel>(s => s.BlockListModelMember));
```

FooModel.cs:

```
public class FooModel 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public BlockListModel BlockListModelMember { get; set; }
}
```

FooViewModel.cs

```
public class FooViewModel 
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<FooCollectionViewModel> BlockListModelMember { get; set; }
}
```

FooCollectionModel.cs

```
public class FooCollectionModel 
{
    public string FooMember { get; set; }
}
```

FooCollectionViewModel.cs

```
public class FooCollectionViewModel 
{
    public string FooMember { get; set; }
}
```

This is how the DI is registered:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddMaps(new[]
            {
                "FooNamespace.Web",
                "FooNamespace.Web.Framework",
            });
        });
```

This particular mapping profile is contained within `FooNamespace.Web`. There are no issues with any other maps in this profile.

`AutoMapper` throws an error that it cannot create an instance of `FooCollectionResolver` at runtime. I believe it attempts to create an instance via reflection when using the generic `.MapFrom<T>` method.

Exception:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Cannot create an instance of type
> GPE.Web.Framework.Mapping.ValueResolvers.FooCollectionResolver`2[FooCollectionModel,FooCollectionViewModel]
>
> AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.CreateInstance(Type type)
>
> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: FooModel -> FooViewModel
>
> Type Map configuration: FooModel -> FooViewModel
>
> Destination Member: BlockListModelMember

Does anyone know why this is?

I can get this working with an inline resolution function e.g:

```
this.CreateMap<FooModel, FooViewModel>()
                .ForMember(
                dest => dest.BlockListModelMember,
                src => src.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) =>
                {
                    // mapping logic
                }));
```

But I want to reuse this logic as its the same general pattern applied to various different models, hence the generic `IMemberValueResolver`

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Is there a reason your class is using `object` here? I would have expected that to be `IMemberValueResolver<TModel, TViewModel,...`

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu OP should include a [mcve] _in the question_. Advising someone to post their [mcve] to an off-site resource is wrong.

Comment: @DavidG - I don't care about the source/destination types, only the member property type so `object` is passed. I don't think that's the issue here as AutoMapper demostrates this pattern in the docs too: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html

Comment: OK, but in this situation you have the types, so why not use them? Also, can you give the full exception message?

Comment: :) That was just an example of how a proper repro would look like.

Comment: @DavidG Because `TModel` and `TViewModel` aren't actually the types it expects as parameters. It wants the source and destination types `TSource`, `TDestination` which would be `FooModel` and `FooViewModel`. `TModel` and `TViewModel` in this example are `FooCollectionModel` and `FooCollectionViewModel`.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#customizing-the-source-value-supplied-to-the-resolver

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/73ba4003e49e37e5fffec49b67e7d9ea1cbb8a8a/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/MemberConfigurationExpression.cs#L41

Comment: Fair enough, another question then, how have you added AutoMapper to your DI container? Can you show the startup code?

Comment: @DavidG I have updated the question to include stack trace + DI setup

Comment: Try an open generic member value resolver. See https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/73ba4003e49e37e5fffec49b67e7d9ea1cbb8a8a/src/UnitTests/OpenGenerics.cs#L250 Also, the DI configuration is broken, see https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html.

Comment: I think that when you call `cfg.AddMaps`, it is missing out a lot of the default AutoMapper configuration and specifically, it is not adding your value resolver to the container. Can you try using `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(FooCollectionResolver<,>).Assembly)` instead? You may need to add other assemblies if you have them.

Comment: @DavidG This was exactly it. Swapping the DI registration to the above solves the issue. Strange, I wouldn't have expected a difference between the two approaches. Seems to be an issue with the `AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> configAction)` overload specifically. Swapping to `AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services, params Assembly[] assemblies)` solves it. If you want to post an answer I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use that specific overload of `services.AddAutoMapper` it is not adding your value resolver to the container. You can use this instead which will scan the assemblies looking for all relevant types:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(
    typeof(FooCollectionResolver<,>).Assembly,
    typeof(SomeOtherType).Assembly /*, more if required */);
```

If you look at the implementation of [AddAutoMapperClasses](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/06df9b2e6cd5604d19d039fde3e8e534ad4929fc/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L64), which is what the `AddAutoMapper` extension method ultimately calls, you will see that it only registers `IMemberValueResolver` types (amoung others) if it's passed a collection of `assembliesToScan`.

The [overload that you're using](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/06df9b2e6cd5604d19d039fde3e8e534ad4929fc/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L26) passes `null` for this parameter so they won't be registered.

Comment: The assembly is implied, you need only specify the type. https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core